# meaning of the pharses combined with the word "ground"

Tags: meaning

What does "fluid ground substance" mean? Does it mean that the substance was ground to fluid or the substance was ground by the fluid? Here it is in context.

> In this case the matrix is the fluid ground substance called plasma.

Comment: *Ground* here is almost certainly the noun meaning the surface of the earth and, by extension, the basis: the substance on which some entity metaphorically rests.

Comment: "Ground substance" is a technical, anatomical term: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ground_substance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP's cited example contains a somewhat quirky sequence of some highly domain-specific terms combined in an unusual way. But I did find these related usages Google Books...

> 1: *Whole blood is often divided into a **matrix,** or liquid fraction, called **plasma** and formed elements, or blood cells.* [Anatomy & Physiology (2015)](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22divided%20into%20a%20matrix%2C%20or%20liquid%20fraction%22)
>   ...and...
>   2: *...the granule-containing alveoli probably move through the **fluid ground substance*** [The Journal of Experimental Zoology (1911)](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22the%20fluid%20ground%20substance%22)
>   ...and...
>   3: *The structural strength of the **ground substance** is also provided by various kinds of fibers* [Applied Kinesiology (2002)](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22the%20ground%20substance%20is%22)

From that it should be clear that a "ground substance" means the ***basic*** material that something's made of. Metaphorically, it's at the "base. bottom, ground-level", before you start "building it up" with additives.

It just looks a bit odd to someone like me when preceded by another adjective such as ***fluid*** (or even [*the **gelatinous** ground substance*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22the%20gelatinous%20ground%20substance%22)), because I'm more likely to associate ***ground*** with ***earth, soil*** (or *reduced to particles in a **grinder***).